# Biber and Perl bug: Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex

Tags: biber, perl

I'm trying to run Biber. However, I get this error in the log file:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\ding{ <-- HERE ([2-9AF][0-9A-F])}/ at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 239.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\A{ <-- HERE \X+}\z/ at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 762.
INFO - This is Biber 2.1
INFO - Logfile is 'these.blg'
INFO - Reading 'these.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblio.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'biblio.bib'
```

I have make a google search, it seems a bug with perl 5.22. However, I have no idea how to fix it. If anyone could help.

Comment: This was fixed in biber >2.1 so that it can be run with perl 5.22.

Comment: I have biber 2.1 installed, and it does not work... Don't know why. Maybe my perl version?

Comment: You need biber >2.1, that is biber 2.2 or later if you want to run it with your own perl 5.22 install.

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem is gone with versions >=2.2 of Biber?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report for a binary, and is now fixed.