# Biber gets perl warning

Tags: biber, perl

I am running Arch Linux and have biber 2.7, perl 5.26.1 and TeXlive 2017 installed from the repositories. However when I compile the tex document

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{t}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the following lit.bib file

```
@book {t,
    TITLE = {Test},
}
```

with pdflatex and then run biber, I get the following warning.

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated here (and will be fatal in Perl 5.30), passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/}(\pM+\pL){ <-- HERE (?!\pL+\\)/ at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 316.
```

Should it be reported as a bug or should I do something else?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error here. However, the space between `book` and `{` in your `lit.bib` does seem strange to me.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290042

Comment: From Nicolas comment, it might be an idea to check upstream tl17 on your arch system, just to verify that it has been fixed in upstream tl and that this update might yet be missing in arch. Nice mwe btw

Comment: Check with `biber --version` which biber you are using, perhaps you have an old one in the path.

Comment: This is a known issue, it will be resolved in the upcoming Biber version (2.8): https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/171

Comment: I guess I should just wait then.

But just to answer some of the responses:

I tried to remove the space between `book` and `{` but I got the same result.

I tried running `biber --version` and got

`Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated here (and will be fatal in Perl 5.30), passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/}(\pM+\pL){ <-- HERE (?!\pL+\\)/ at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 316.`

`biber version: 2.7`

Comment: daleif: I'm not sure how to check this. Does [this](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/texlive-most/) contain the information?

Comment: Not really, using upstream TL means manually installing tl and not using the arch one. But it would probably not matter as it is something that is being fixed on the biber side, but not yet released.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem and has already been brought to PLK's attention. He has committed a fix that will be in the next release of Biber (2.8). See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/171 and https://github.com/plk/biber/commit/c029e218321a3fa01647ded8f0a05b31dc53c9ed